# Numpy matrix rotation for any degrees

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I try to find a way to apply a matrix rotation of any degrees on my matrix that contains three bands like RGB but values are bigger than (0-255).

It is an example of my data its shape is (100, 100, 3):

```
 [[ 847.5  877.   886.  ...  821.5  856.5  898. ]
 [ 850.   883.   969.5 ...  885.   878.5  947.5]
 [ 982.   968.5  927.5 ...  909.5  958.  1037. ]
 ...
 [ 912.   827.   893.  ... 1335.  1180.  1131. ]
 [ 954.   855.5  882.  ... 1252.  1266.  1335. ]
 [ 984.   916.   930.  ... 1080.5 1278.  1385.5]]
```

I found a function `scipy.misc.imrotate(image_array, 20)` but the problem is this function rescales my data to the range (0-255), thus I loose information of my original matrix. Is there a function that does the same job as the previous one without rescaling data ?

Comment: Why not implement [matrix rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried `rotate` function from [scipy.ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

x = np.random.randint(800, 1000, size=[100, 100, 3])
rotated = rotate(x, angle=45)
```

It does rotate matrix without scaling the values.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it achieves what I want. To keep the same shape as the input i.e (100,100,3) I just need to add an extra parameter which is `rotate(x, angle=45, reshape=False)`

Comment: This rotate operation from scipy changes the intensity values of objects, I just checked and compared with the ones obtained from PIL.Image.rotate. I am trying to avoid PIL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try open CV's [warpAffine()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html).
It allows for rotation and translation of the image.

Depending on your choice of interpolation method you might have some changes to your values thoug.