# Is there an easier way of transforming this scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I want to use sparse matrices to store a "map" of occupied/free space detected by a laser range finder. I think sparse matrices are a good fit to this problem because there is much more free space in the environment (denoted with 0s), than there are obstacles (denoted with 1s, or a float between 0 and 1 for probability).

After acquiring this map, as part of a matching algorithm I want to apply different spatial transformations to it, such as, but not necessarily limited to, rotations and translations.

As a proof of concept for the transformations part, I have this small SciPy sparse matrix defined in coordinates format (`coo_matrix`) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

row = np.array([2])
col = np.array([2])
data = np.array([1])
shape = (4, 4)
m = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape)
```

```py
m.toarray()

array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to, for example, rotate this matrix 90 degrees counter-clockwise around its center, to get this new matrix:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

What I did was:

1. Get the coordinates for the non-zero point:

```py
point = [m.col[0], m.row[0], 1]

[2, 2, 1]
```

2. Calculate the transformation matrix corresponding to a) putting the center at `(1.5, 1.5)` and b) rotating 90 degrees counter-clockwise:

```py
rot = np.array([[0, -1, 3],[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1]])

array([[ 0, -1,  3],
       [ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1]])
```

3. Apply the transformation by multiplying the point at 1) with the matrix at 2):

```py
rot.dot(point)

array([1, 2, 1])
```

Which effectively has rotated point at `(2,2)` to `(1,2)` (or to `(1,2,1)` in homogeneous coordinates which is the same), with center on `(1.5, 1.5)`.

Now, this feels rather "manual". Is there a shorter way of applying this transformation? I know there is some quaternion-based rotation supported by scipy but I'm more interested in a general approach that can include not only rotations but translations and basically any transformation (scipy only supports rotations for now anyways).

Is there a more direct way of transforming this matrix without having to manually a) build each non-zero point from coordinates and b) applying the transform to each point?

Note: I'm using sparse matrices for convenience and storage, but if as an intermediate step it had to be converted to another format, transformed, and converted back to sparse, that's ok too.

Thanks!

Comment: Something is probably wrong in your example of rotation of "90 degrees counter-clockwise": the matrix seem rotated of 180 degrees.

Comment: The sparse matrix format is good for matrix multiplication.  For anything else I'd try to use the dense arrays.

Comment: @JérômeRichard you're right, I've fixed the example. However the rotation result seems good to me, right? (2,2) converted to (1,2) is a 90 degree rotation, keeping in mind it means (row, col) and not (x,y), which was what confused me.

Comment: @hpaulj suppose we used in fact a dense array. How would the implementation of a transform look like? Wouldn't I end up calculating the coordinates to transform them individually, regardless of which original matrix representation I use? Thanks!

Comment: Does https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html help?

Comment: @albert well, that looks specific for the 90 degrees rotation, I'm interested in applying any transforms in general. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171057/numpy-matrix-rotation-for-any-degrees

Comment: You/we need a clearer idea of your purpose, your ultimate goal.  `np.transpose`, `np.flip`, `np.rot90` is one category of transformations.  Right or left (or both) multiplying by a 'rotation' matrix is another.  Image rotation is a much bigger topic, since it also has to consider scaling, interpolation, smoothing and other things to avoid distorting an image.

Comment: @hpaulj I want to store a SLAM occupancy grid in this matrix, and transform it in several way as part of the scan matching algorithm. I'll add this context to the question.